# L2 norm and the Kullback distance

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

Let $P$ and $Q$ be two probability measures with densities $p$ and $q$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure on [0,1] such that: $0<a\leq p(x)\leq b$, $0<a\leq q(x)\leq b$ $\forall x\in $[0,1] $a$,$b>0$ are constants. Show that the Kullback distance $K(P,Q)$ is equivalent to the squared $L^2$ distance between densities $p$ and $q$.

this is what i did:

I want to show there are two constants $\alpha$ and $\beta$ such that $\alpha||p-q||^{2}\leq K(P,Q)\leq \beta ||p-q||^{2}$
Using the Taylor theorem i have 
$K(P,Q)\leq \int(p-q) +\frac{1}{2a}(\frac{b}{a})^{2}\int(q-p)^2$ and i don't know how prove that $\int(p-q)=0$  to get a first inequality.

Some help would be appreciated

Comment: $\int p = \int q = 1$ since $p$ and $q$ are probability densities, therefore $\int (p-q) = 0$.

Comment: ok, i understand. but why the Kullback distance is well defined? why $P << Q$ and $Q << P$ ?